# Losing my vocal range?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, vocal-cords, bass-voice

Just over four days ago I had a comfortable chest range of D2-F#4 but over the last two to three days it's been "reduced" down to E2-E4. I can still inch down to D2 (while sounding a bit vocal-fry-ish, which I never did) and up to F#4 but it's kind of a struggle to do so whereas before I could easily get there. Any insight as to why this is happening to me and whether or not it is permanent? 
I'm 17 by the way

Comment: Did you catch an illness over the last few days?

Comment: Yes, what else has happened in the last few days? So many things can affect range: sleep, illness, hydration level, overuse, etc., but generally all of those things are temporary. If you take a day off and make sure you rest and get well-hydrated, it should come back.

Comment: Nope, I've been perfectly healthy and decently hydrated. Haven't been singing that much nor overusing my voice, just messing around with some bass lines or humming along to songs mostly

Comment: At 17 you haven't yet fully established your vocal range - It might still change tomorrow.

Comment: Just about the same thing happened to me...

Answer (score 1):

As Todd Wilcox commented, many many things can change vocal range for a few days.

Permanent changes happen much more slowly:  puberty, aging a few decades, deliberately using bad technique for many months.